# Angular Service regarding specific functionality?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know what would be the best method to allow the following function.

1. User will input search query from index page into single input box
2. Upon submit user will redirect to second view with displayed data

This function will have 2 pages relevant. However the data page must be url friendly which means the user should be able to access that url and retrieve the data as well as being able to do the submit query method on index page.

I presume i would need a service for this but would i use $location to pass the query to create the redirect url and then do the logic in the controller of the second page?

I am just trying to figure out how this functionality should work in theory.

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the following are the "things" you will need:

**Two Routes with Controllers and Templates**

- The first route should handle the home page with the input box. There is nothing special about that.
- The second route needs to serve a component which is handling the details page. This route needs to have a path with a variable (e.g. `/users/:userId`) which you will be able to access in your controller through `$stateParameters` (if you chose to use `ui-router`).

**Service**

You should also create a separate service which will handle the search request to your (or third-party) API. This is a good practice as your controllers should not be handling data retrievals. They should be concerned with when to get the data rather than how - that is what the service is for.

Comment: Does this essentially mean that the controller for users/:userId will be handles when accessing the page using a service. Where as the first controller will send the search query using redirect? This is essentially how i thought it would work.